# CUPS error log contains "No such interface `org.freedesktop.ColorManager'"

Tags: cups

On my Ubuntu 13.04 laptop, CUPS writes this message into `/var/log/cups/error_log` for each printer on restart:

```
W [25/Jun/2013:10:00:26 +0100] AddProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod:No such interface `org.freedesktop.ColorManager' on object at path /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_Brother_HL_2150N_series
```

I'm not having any problems printing, but I'd like to know why the message appears and what I can do about it.  Ideally I'd like to fix the problem without blindly installing drivers and packages; I want to understand precisely why the message appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with @don_crissti that this is most likely being caused by the ColorManager interface, (i.e. [org.freedesktop.ColorManager](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/colord/gtk-doc/ColorManager.html)). If you're not familiar with ICC profiles they're profiles which describe a particular device's color attributes, you printer in this case.

You can read more about [ICC Profiles here on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile), or [color management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_management) in general.

So usually there is software that comes with the printer that will allow you to create your own profiles or use stock ones that come with the device. CUPS, ColorManager in this case, is complaining because it can't find these profiles.

Now is where my knowledge on the subject starts to really drop off, so I have to revert to my hacking skills. If you look for "icc" on your system, using say the `locate` command, you'll find some files which are color profiles:

```
$ locate "/icc"
...
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sk1/share/icc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sk1/share/icc/GenericCMYK.icm
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sk1/share/icc/sRGB.icm
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sk1/share/icc/sRGB_Color_Space_Profile.icm
...
/usr/share/color/icc/AdobeGammaTest.icm
/usr/share/color/icc/Argyll
/usr/share/color/icc/Fogra27L.icc
/usr/share/color/icc/bluish.icc
/usr/share/color/icc/Argyll/ClayRGB1998.icm
/usr/share/color/icc/Argyll/lab2lab.icm
/usr/share/color/icc/Argyll/sRGB.icm
...
```

These profiles aren't necessarily for just printers, any input or output device can use them (scanners, monitors, etc.). The above are just some examples to show you what's going on.

If you poke around under the preferences dialog of your printer you'll probably see something like this:

```
$ system-config-printer
```

*select a printer that features color printing and right click on it and select properties*

[image: ss of printers]

[image: ss of properties right click]

*select "Printer Options" you'll see the color modes that are available*

[image: ss of printer's color modes]

#### So why the error message?

So what's most likely happening is that the print driver you've selected for this printer is looking for .icm files that either the printer does not offer by default or the files are not present on your system.

Typically when I've encountered this error I've switches to a different driver from the same manufacturer or used some generic drivers but each situation is different so it's hard to give specifics.

#### References

- [Where does Gnome Color Manager store the ICM or ICC files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155552/where-does-gnome-color-manager-store-the-icm-or-icc-files)

Comment: Top banana -- this is exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!